# Is there any device that receives WiFi signal and translate to an ethernet?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I was looking for a device that receives my house WiFI and gives me an ethernet, if possible a very high speed WiFi, I would like to put cables everywhere but I can't actually, so this would be my solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty much all wifi routers do this...

Comment: The reverse thing? to receive a current WiFi from my other router and give me ethernet connection to it?

Comment: This is called a `USB 802.11 Wireless Adapter` just purchase the adapter that supports the 802.11 mode supported by your wireless access point.

Comment: Please clarify your question.   Please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.  Are you trying to convert an Ethernet-only device to connect via WiFi instead?

Comment: Yes, you can set up a wifi router in [bridge mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_bridge).

Comment: @StraightAE - Yes;  You can connect to a wireless router and use a lan ethernet cable.  You can nothing but doing so because your internet speed is capped at the 802.11 mode speeds.  So your better off connecting directly to the wireless network.

Comment: How limited will my bandwidth be? I have wrt54g router, can I do this with it?

Comment: Like everything else, your speeds will be limited by the slowest link - so all clients connected to the AP Client would be communicating through the single wireless link.  This means the link's bandwidth would be shared with all the clients, and would likely be the bottleneck.

Comment: This might be overkill, as you may not have a need for a print server, but will do what you're asking: http://support.netgear.com/product/WGPS606

Comment: @StraightAE a wrt54g router will be quite slow as it uses old 802.11g technology rather then 802.11n.  Depending on the distance from your router I'd expect speeds of 5-10 megabit, with a theoretical maximum of about 50 megabit (Decent 802.11n gear with multiple antennas would boost this speed by 3-10 times)

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is called an "AP Client" (or Access Point Client).  Some routers can be run in this mode "off-the-shelf", but a better option might be to get one which can run DD-WRT and simply use that.

An AP Client (when connected to an access point or WIFI router) basically converts between WIFI and Ethernet ports - without routing packets - ie it turns your WIFI into a virtual Ethernet cable and converts it into a physical one.

For a high speed connection though, you might want to get a couple of dual band routers (configure 1 as an AP or router and one as an AP Client) and use the 5 gig band to communicate between the routers, and the 2.4 gig band for general communications for the house.

[ I do note that a repeater can be used as well, however that is going to be less efficient as it rebroadcasts signals ]